# Is it safe to place a keytab on a external server

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, spnego

I wonder if we could place a keytab from our internal active-directory on a web-server out in the wild.

If I'm not completely wrong, there is no direct communication between the web-server and the active directory. SPNEGO does any negotiation across the client connection.
Therefore this should work, but is it secure ?

Let's assume, the web server gets hacked, and the attacker can access the keytab file.
May/does this affect the security of our internal active-directory or do I "only" have a compromised web-server ?
Can the keytab file be used to figure out some internals of our network ?

Edit: to clarify, wikipedia provides a good article to better describe the situation. I'm talking about the Kc-s where we share a keytab between TGS and SS

[image]

Kerberos protocol by Jeran Renz, CC BY-SA 4.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0, via Wikimedia Commons
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)

Comment: _"there is no direct communication between the web-server and the active directory ... SPNEGO does any negotiation across the client connection"_ >> er... before the nego itself, the client **and** the server must obtain a TGT _(ID token)_ from the KDC -- in your case, the KDC is an AD Domain Server. Then the client obtains the appropriate service ticket _(access token)_ and provides it to the server.

Comment: The whole point of having a keytab file is to allow _services_ to authenticate against the KDC in non-interactive mode.

Comment: On a higher perspective, the purpose of Kerberos is to manage secure authentication across an insecure network. It does nothing to protect the credentials on the remote hosts (except by ensuring that once an attacker is detected, it can be blocked "eventually" by preventing him to renew the compromised creds)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter after your first comment I did a lot of RFC reading, where I found RFC5588 credential store extensions, which leaded me to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol). Probably it wasn't clear enough. Looking at wikipedia I'm talking about Client Service Request, where the Ks is shared between the Service Server (SS) and the TGS. I this case Imho the SS will not need any access to  the TGS or AS - is this still wrong ?

Comment: Duh. In my humble understanding of the way it works in practise, the AS is "your" AD Domain server, and the TGS is "the web server's" AD Domain Server -- and there's a trust between Domain servers (with possibly an extra hop to the "root" AD Domain server but that's more about routing the requests)

Comment: When you talk about "the AD" in general, that's a bunch of different services on (possibly) different machines, with redundancy, local mirrors of remote Domain servers, etc.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: When acting as a Kerberos SPNEGO server, the service does not need to obtain a TGT nor talk to the KDC in any way at all. It only _accepts_ tickets, not provides its own, and the purpose of the keytab is that it could decrypt/verify tickets accepted from its clients.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: The AS and the TGS are only conceptually two services, but in practice they're both provided by the same KDC (or "domain controller" in AD), and both are used by the _client_ -- not by the SPNEGO service.

Answer (score 3):

The keytab file is just a mapping of SPNs to keys. The keys are the literal keys used to authenticate the service into Active Directory, or to verify tickets from Active Directory to the service.

So this is therefore equivalent to an attacker getting ahold of the service SPN and their password. Whether that's really bad or only kinda bad is something only you can decide.